# Angular JS, remember checkbox status when filtering

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to create a list with checkboxes with a search box.

HTML

```
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="query">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:query">
      <input type="checkbox" id="{{item.id}}" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
```

JS

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Green",
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Yellow",
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Blue",
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Red",
    }
  ];
});
```

The problem is that the checkboxes status are not saved when I'm searching through the search box. For example, when I check "Green", I type on text box something else, then remove this text, the checked "Green" is not checked anymore. How can I have "memory" on checkboxes status?

Here is a link to plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/KHq3AA4guGKA4AqxQrF8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggested you to add one more property in your `items` array each `item`, that would be accessible as `item.checked`

**Markup**

```
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="query">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:query">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked">{{item.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/PlB74HswMp59zBqaFIN9?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you... it was so easy!

Comment: @PankajParkar could you take a look at my question?  For some reason I cannot attach a value to my `ng-model` when I check a box I get the following error - `TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'entityChecked'`.  Here is my question if you have the time - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35276014/checkbox-unchecking-itself-after-angularjs-filter-applied

Comment: Will look at it..once i will have machine.

Answer (score 1):

attach `ng-model="item.checked"` to checkbox like:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked" id="{{item.id}}" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}
```

see this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/22aVE9gWqkBU85GzsEln?p=preview)

Comment: I marked as a correct answer the first one, thanks for your time.