# Checkbox Unchecking after AngularJS sorting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat

I currently have a table listing `jobs`.  Each `job` has a checkbox.

```
<form name="jobsSampleSelectForm" id="jobs-sample-select-form">
    <div  jobs="data">
      <div ng-form="jobsSampleSelectForm">
        <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true">
            <tr ng-repeat="job in $data" class="table-highlight" ng-class="{deactivated: job.is_active == 'No'}">
                <td data-title="'Sample'"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="job.selected"></td>
                <td data-title="'QC ID'" sortable="'id'"><a href="#/jobs/{{job.id}}">{{job.id}}</a></td>
                <td data-title="'Date Submitted'" sortable="'dateJob'">{{job.dateJob}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
      </div></div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary-red" ng-click="sampleJobs()" ng-disabled="(jobs | filter: job.selected != true).length <= 0">Sample Jobs</button>
</form>
```

This allows the user to select the jobs they want.  However, when the user sorts a column the checkbox will uncheck itself.  This seems to be a common issue, so from the advice from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35276014/checkbox-unchecking-itself-after-angularjs-filter-applied) I added a `selected` attribute to each job in my controller.

```
jobsService.getJobsByStatuses(["pre_sampling", "sampling", "setup"])
    .success(function(data){
        data.forEach(function(job){ job.selected = false; });
        $scope.jobs = data;
        var filteredData = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')(data, params.filter()) : data;
        var orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) : data;

        $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
        params.total(orderedData.length);
})
```

This did not seem to cause a difference.  What am I missing?

---

I created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h86mmsh1/) to show the basic idea.  When the user selects checkboxes, then sorts, the checkboxes become unchecked.

Comment: Can you add a JS Fiddle or Plunker link?

Comment: @NobalMohan I can try!

Comment: @NobalMohan Added a fiddle!

Comment: Thanks, Sara. The fiddle helped to solve the problem. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was calling `getData` every time a filter was applied.  This was setting my `selected` attribute on each job to false.  To fix this issue, I moved my code to get the data outside of the `getData` function.

Answer (score 1):

just change
`<td data-title="'Sample'"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="job.selected"></td>`
   to
`<td data-title="'Sample'"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.selected"></td>`

If you want to persist the row selection then you should bind the checkbox to `user.selected` instead of binding to `job.selected`.

If you use `user.selected` for ng-model each row will have its own `user` object with `selected` property binded to checkbox so that you will get the selection even after the sorting

see the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gangadharjannu/watkn10h/)

Comment: Sorry, I kind of merged my code with an existing fiddle, so in my code, as you can see in the snippet, I already have `ng-model="job.selected"`.  Let me see if I can update the Fiddle

Comment: no change `ng-model="job.selected" ` to `ng-model="user.selected" `

Comment: My actual code is in the code snippet above.  I do not user `user`, I use `job`

Comment: I understand that.  But if you look in my code in the question (not in the Fiddle) I never use `user`.  `user` would be undefined

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.selected">
```

Working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PQvQ2/83/

You are not capturing the checkbox value anywhere. In the user object, you already have "selected" to capture the selection. Using the same will store the selection. If you are using a different object "job", you will capture the index of selection but it will not be mapped to the correct value. Since, "job" object only store the checkbox selected, nothing more.

Comment: Sorry, I kind of merged my code with an existing fiddle, so in my code, as you can see in the snippet, I already have `ng-model="job.selected"`.  Let me see if I can update the Fiddle